# Is Parallel.ForEach loop supported on Windows 2008 R2 server without SP1?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

From the **[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx)** under Platform section, It says It would run only if Server Core supported with SP1 or later.

Specs of my server are:

> **Processor**: Intel Xenon 2.93GHz (4 Processors)
>   **System Type**: 64-bit
>   **OS**: Windows Server R2 Enterprise

**Another Question:**

What is meant by "Server Core not supported"?

**Accepted Answer**

Accepted answer and **[post by Marius Oiaga](http://news.softpedia.com/news/NET-Framework-4-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2-SP1-Server-Core-179774.shtml)** helped here. It says.

> **Customers will need Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 in order to take advantage of .Net Framework 4 on server core deployments.**

Comment: What is your *first* question?  We use Windows 2008 R2 servers here, and I can run `Parallel.ForEach` just fine across 12 cores.

Comment: The first question was in question title. In the documentation, it says, it should have SP1 or later. Without SP1, it won't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server core is a streamlined install of server missing much of the non essential features (including the majority of the gui's)

If you have a gui on your server, you should be fine.

Comment: If you are running server core you must have R2 sp1 according to that doc.

Comment: @Keneth, Thanks. This clarifies Server Code option. Yes GUI is enabled on the server.